# can't replace ? in csv file?

Tags: microsoft-excel

There are some `?` in a column content, now i want to replace it with a batch. when i <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>,put the `?` in the replace box.then click ok, it shows  the formula  is too long。 how do i do? thank you

Comment: What tool are you using for this search and replace? If you can to regex replaces its a simple s/\?/STUFFHERE/g

Comment: You might need to include some screenshots of data and dialog interaction before this will make sense to someone else.

Comment: @Nick, the question specifically mentions "excel" in the tags, and "ctrl+f" in the text. I think the "tool" being used is pretty clear - it's the "Find" dialog in Excel itself, which is why the question is off-topic.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake, I didn't see that you had tagged it with excel.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `?` with a `~`, otherwise the `?` is used as a wild card.  That is, put `~?` in the `Find What` box

Comment: i am sorry it doesn't work. i want to replace ? to no content.namely,delete it. i used ~? it can't replace with null content

Comment: Yes you can, just leave the `Replace with` box empty

Comment: This is the right answer. I accidentally upvoted the comment that said it doesn't work and can't remove my upvote, so please ignore it.